# How to check for inf? Swift xcode7

Tags: swift

How do I check in Swift if the result of a calculation is not infinite?

My code below is crashing after printing that"dividepointsbyrest  is
inf".  "if dividepointsbyrest != nil" checks for nil. 'if dividepointsbyrest != inf' does not work.

```
var dividepointsbyrest = (BPMpoints / restDouble)
    print("dividepointsbyrest is") 
    print(dividepointsbyrest) 

    var BPMpercentD = 100.0 * dividepointsbyrest
```

Comment: `if restDouble != 0 { ... }`, perhaps you could also __prevent__ dividing by zero.

Comment: good idea, thank you. The restDouble is not zero, but yes I am trying to prevent the division returning inf- I think the problem is that it's trying to divide by larger number. Am checking, I think BPMpoints is zero. Will try that

Comment: you are right, restDouble was zero. Good spot. So that code would help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Double` has an `isInfinite`/`isFinite` properties for that.

```
if dividepointsbyrest.isInfinite {
    print("dividepointsbyrest is infinite")
}
```

or

```
if dividepointsbyrest.isFinite {
    print("dividepointsbyrest is finite")
}
```